# Create arrows (without arrowheads) and write inside text-boxes

Tags: environments, geometry

I can't think of a decent way to ask this question, so here's an image. Please feel free to modify the title, post or the tags.
[image]

I would like to use this repetitively where I write something (*"some writing.."*) and use arrows to some more text-boxes (where the boxes do not have to be visible) and I write inside each of those text boxes (*"more writing"*).

I use MikTex and TeXworks if that is necessary.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I have no idea how to do this. I don't know how to use environments or TikZ, assuming these may be required for this.

Comment: Technically, `document` is an environment, or is at least uses the same protocol.

Comment: This image remind me on tree. It can be simple drawing by use `tikz` (Making Trees Grow, page 332), `forest`, or `tikz-qtree`. Search for question with these tags. Regarding environment, you can put this image in `figure` or `center` environment. Which documentclass you use?

Comment: @Zarko I'll look that up, thank you. I'm using *article*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to use LuaLaTeX (also available with MiKTeX), you can use TikZ libraries `graph` + `graphdrawing` for this:

```
%!TeX lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph [binary tree layout,level distance=30mm] {
    some writing some writing some writing -- {
      {more writing 1},
      {more writing 2},
      {more writing 3}
    }
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: tree using TikZ libraries graphs and graphdrawing and LuaLaTeX]

See the [TikZ user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), chapter 27, *Introduction to Algorithmic Graph Drawing* for more information.

However, there are also suggestions, which do not need LuaLaTeX but also work with PDFLaTeX of XeLaTeX, e.g., using TikZ library trees:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {some writing some writing some writing}
  [grow via three points={
    one child at (-3,-2) and two children at (-3,-2) and (0,-2)}]
  child {node {more writing 1}}
  child {node {more writing 2}}
  child {node {more writing 3}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: tree using TikZ library trees and pdflatex]

See chapter 76, *Tree Library* of the
[TikZ user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) for more information.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot cabohah!

Answer (score 2):

With use of the `forest` package and its library (loaded as package option), drawing of your diagram is simple. MWE (Minimal Working Example) below, you can compile with pdfLateX, XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{forest}
for tree = {l sep=13mm}
[some writing some writing some writing 
    [more writing 1]
    [more writing 2]
    [more writing 3]
]
\end{forest}
    \end{figure}
    
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative using `forest`. You can change `l sep` (level seperation) to increase or decrease vertical spacing, and change `s sep` (sibling separation) to change horizontal spacing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north, l sep=1.5cm, s sep=1cm}
[Some writing some writing some writing
    [more writing 1]
    [more writing 2]
    [more writing 3]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

The `forest` package has *many* options for altering the look of your tree. Adding levels is easy too. Just add nodes in square brackets. For example:

```
[Some writing some writing some writing
    [more writing 1
        [more 11a][more 1b]
    ]
    [more writing 2
        [more 2a][more 2]
    ]
    [more writing 3
        [more 3a][more 3b][more 3c]
    ]
]
```

[image]